# Is it possible to install pandoc on windows using an R command?

Tags: r, windows-7, pandoc

I would like to download and install pandoc on a windows 7 machine, by running a command in R.  Is that possible?

(I know I can do this manually, but when I'd show this to students - the more steps I can organize within an R code chunk - the better)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about simply downloading the most recent version of the installer and starting that from R:

1. a) Identify the most recent version of Pandoc and grab the URL with the help of the `XML` package:

   ```
   library(XML)
   page     <- readLines('http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/downloads/list', warn = FALSE)
   pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(page, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE, encoding='UTF-8')
   url      <- xpathSApply(pagetree, '//tr[2]//td[1]//a ', xmlAttrs)[1]
   url      <- paste('http', url, sep = ':')
   ```

   b) Or apply some regexp magic thanks to *@G.Grothendieck* instead (no need for the `XML` package this way):

   ```
   page <- readLines('http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/downloads/list', warn = FALSE)
   pat  <- "//pandoc.googlecode.com/files/pandoc-[0-9.]+-setup.exe"
   line <- grep(pat, page, value = TRUE); m <- regexpr(pat, line)
   url  <- paste('http', regmatches(line, m), sep = ':')
   ```

   c) Or simply check the most recent version manually if you'd feel like that:

   ```
   url <- 'http://pandoc.googlecode.com/files/pandoc-1.10.1-setup.exe'
   ```
2. Download the file as `binary`:

   ```
   t <- tempfile(fileext = '.exe')
   download.file(url, t, mode = 'wb')
   ```
3. And simply run it from R:

   ```
   system(t)
   ```
4. Remove the needless file after installation:

   ```
   unlink(t)
   ```

---

PS: sorry, only tested on Windows XP

Comment: Great!
Any way to recognize the latest version automatically?

Comment: @TalGalili: sure, I've added a hopefully working way to recognize the latest version.

Comment: Ah, and sorry for frequent edits, I won't touch this post any more. I promise :)

Comment: To get rid of XML but still extract the exact file name try this: `pat <- "//pandoc.googlecode.com/files/pandoc-[0-9.]+-setup.exe";
target.line <- grep(pat, page, value = TRUE);
m <- regexpr(pat, target.line);
regmatches(target.line, m)`  (The `http` still needs to be prepended.)

Comment: Great solution guys!
Thanks daroczig - it's fun to learn new stuff like this.  Also, thank you Grothendieck for the extra solution

Comment: Thank you @G.Grothendieck, I have update the answer based on your really cool regexp wizardry.

Comment: I think the `target.line<-` got dropped

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: that's right, thanks (and sorry), I've just fixed that.

Comment: Hi Daroczig and Grothendieck.  Based on this thread, I've decided to create an R package with install.x type functions.  I've published it here: https://github.com/talgalili/installr/  And would appreciate any comments (including if you'd like credit somewhere, which you think you deserve.  I gave some in some of the functions already.  But I might have missed something).  Again, thank you very much.  Tal